# setComponentOrientation does not have effect on form designer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jradiobutton

I have right to left JFrame in swing with netbeans. there is radio button in it which is `setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)`. When I execute the program the orientation is fine. but in GUI builder it shows like this:

[image]

Is this netbeans problem? Can it be resolved?

Comment: for `JCheckBox` and `JRadioButton` ??? you have to ??? 1) programatically by using `SwingConstants.LEFT` or `RIGHT`, 2) apply the `ComponentOrientation` to `JCheckBox` and `JRadioButton` too, never tried,sorry ...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Netbeans Matisse. You can create a issue here: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling [`applyComponentOrientation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#applyComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29) on the `Container` that has the buttons. Since you're using the GUI editor, you'll probably have to use custom code.